# Dynamic Views from JSON file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create views from JSON!when i use my state array to render each element in render() function it is printing the last indexed element, how can i loop through my state array. Here is my code to achieve this!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
const data = require("../json/data.json");

class InfoScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemstorender: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderData();
  }

  renderData = () => {
    const { id } = this.props.route.params;
    const result = data.info[id].child;
    // console.log(result);
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].type == "text") {
        this.setState({
          itemstorender: <TextInput key={result.key} placeholder={result[i].label} />
        
        });
      } else if (result[i].type == "button") {
        this.setState({
          itemstorender: <Button key={result.key} title={result[i].label} />,
        });
      }
    }
  };


}

export default InfoScreen;
```

my render() function!

```
 render() {
    return (
        <View>
            { this.state.itemstorender }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
renderData = () => {
    const { id } = this.props.route.params;
    const result = data.info[id].child;
    // console.log(result);
    var itemstorenderLocal = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      
     if (result[i].type == "text") {
        itemstorenderLocal.push(<TextInput key={result.key} placeholder={result[i].label} />);
      } else if (result[i].type == "button") {
        itemstorenderLocal.push(<Button key={result.key} title={result[i].label} />);
      }
    }
    
    this.setState({
       itemstorender: itemstorenderLocal
    });

  };
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked perfectly.. i want to ask you one more thing related to this.

Comment: Yes sure please ask

Comment: how can i get values from each element? elements could be of different types. like radio button,spinner,check box etc.